# Counting the amount of times a number shows up as the first digit in a data set

Tags: python

I have a dataset as a .txt file like this:

```
17900
66100
11300
94600
10600
28700
37800
```

I want to extract the first digit from every number in my dataset and then count how many times that number appears as the first digit in my dataset. How would I solve that in python code?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: When asking about homework
**(1)** Be aware of your school policy: asking here for help may constitute *cheating*.
**(2)** Specify that the question is homework.
**(3)** Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first (include your code in your question).
**(4)** Ask about a specific problem with your existing implementation; see [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
Also, [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) is guidance on asking homework questions.

Answer (score 1):

With the data file called `data.txt`.

```
from collections import Counter 

with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
  firsts = [int(line[0]) for line in f.readlines()]
result = Counter(firsts)
print(result)
```

This will print a dictionary with `firstvalue: count`.

Answer (score 0):

I will not write the code here but mention the approach.

1. Use open and readlines to parse lines from the file
2. Initialize a dictionary to use for the purpose of tracking
   counts
3. Now you have a list of lines containing the numbers as strings
4. Access the first element of each line and check in a dictionary
   if it was already seen
   A. if seen, then increment the value
   B. if new then assign 1 as the value